# Array Splitting in Python With Specific Input

Tags: python, list, split

If you are given two arrays as an input in the same line such as

`[4,2,1,5,7],[4,1,2,3,5,7,1,2,7]`

Is it possible to create separate arrays out of the above input?

```
arr1 = [4,2,1,5,7]
arr2 = [4,1,2,3,5,7,1,2,7]
```

I tried to use `split(',')` but since they are used in the actual arrays this does not work.

The length of the arrays can vary and the example above is just a sample.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe show us the rest of the code, because that input seems suspect to me.

Comment: Is that the _actual_ input on the console? With the inner brackets but no outer brackets?

Comment: @Chris I just want to experiment with the arrays and iterate through them since I am new and learning. But I can't seem to figure out how to split the input into two different arrays.

Comment: @DYZ I know it's a bit strange but yes that is the exact input on the console

Comment: If you are starting with a string, it would be clearer so make it explicit: `"[4,2,1,5,7],[4,1,2,3,5,7,1,2,7]"` If you aren't starting with a string, the problem doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I'm going to bet that what you have is a string, not lists

Comment: And FYR: They are not arrays. They are lists.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest "disguising" the input as a well-formed list by adding the outer brackets and then using `literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = "[4,2,1,5,7],[4,1,2,3,5,7,1,2,7]"
parts = ast.literal_eval("[" + s + "]")
#[[4, 2, 1, 5, 7], [4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7]]
```

Or do not add anything and treat the input as a tuple of lists:

```
parts = ast.literal_eval(s)
#([4, 2, 1, 5, 7], [4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7])
```

Comment: It will work even without adding extra `[]`, and will parse into a tuple.

Comment: @bereal Fair enogh.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there, once converted from a string using `eval`, is a 2-element tuple containing two lists. (The outer round parentheses are not mandatory in this situation.)

You could unpack it into two variables as follows:

```
str = '[4,2,1,5,7],[4,1,2,3,5,7,1,2,7]'

arr1, arr2 = eval(str)
```

---

**Note**: if the input string could derive from third-party input (for example in a server application) then eval should not be used for security reasons because it can allow for execution of arbitrary code, and `ast.literal_eval` should be used instead.  (See separate answer by DYZ.)  This will also return a 2-tuple of lists in the case of the input shown above, so the unpacking using `var1, var2 = ...` is unaffected.

Comment: DO NOT use `eval`. [Eval is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: @DYZ I've added a note now.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the easy way, but if the goal is to learn to manipulate strings and lists, you *can* actually parse this the hard way as a stream of characters.

```
a = "[4,2,1,5,7],[45,1,2,3,5,7,100,2,7]"

l = []

current_n = ''
current_l = None

for c in a:
    if c == '[':
        current_l = []
    elif c == ",":
        if current_l is not None:
            current_l.append(int(current_n))
            current_n = ''
    elif c.isdigit():
        current_n += c
    elif c == "]":
        current_l.append(int(current_n))
        l.append(current_l)
        current_n = ''
        current_l = None

l1, l2  = l
print(l1, l2)
# [4, 2, 1, 5, 7] [45, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 100, 2, 7]
```

Not something you would typically do, but a good exercise and it's simplicity should make is quite fast.